# Automapper, report updated properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

I am storing orders in a database from a daily csv file.

Each line is parsed into an class object with one property per column.
Then this object is  transformed into an entity using automapper.

Some order have updated fields and I would like to report all changes saved.

I use automapper to update the database object and use `db.Entry(order).State` to detect when a change has been made.

The logical approach seem to loop through the properties using reflection `order.GetType().GetProperties()` and test if values are different: `if(!Equals(propertyInfo.GetValue(updatedOrder), propertyInfo.GetValue(order)))`

Is there a way to do this easily without looping a second time on each property using automapper or shall I just get rid of automapper in that case ?

Answer (score 1):

I do this in the data access layer by only using the `DbEntityEntry`. It doesn't avoid a loop through all properties though:

```
    private static IEnumerable<string> GetModifiedProperties(DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry)
    {
        foreach (var propertyName in dbEntityEntry.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
        {
            var originalValue = dbEntityEntry.OriginalValues[propertyName];
            var currentValue = dbEntityEntry.CurrentValues[propertyName];

            if (!Equals(originalValue, currentValue))
            {
                yield return propertyName;
            }
        }
    }
```

This method is being called from the overridden `SaveChanges` method of the `DbContext`, before calling `base.SaveChanges()`.

Comment: Ths question is about ef-core, where this is a lot simpler. You can simply use `EntityEntry.Properties` and see the state, original value, and current value of each individual property.

Comment: ok that lead me to the solution I wanted. if (db.Entry(order).State != EntityState.Unchanged), I can loop through db.Entry(order).Properties.Where(t => t.IsModified); and put that in a report: $"{propertyEntry.Metadata.Name}: {propertyEntry.OriginalValue} =>  {propertyEntry.CurrentValue}"